# how to hide access token in angular and spring application?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

i want hide access token from header while requesting.and need to hide it in response

we are normally getting  access token by spring boot application.i need to hide it when response come from spring and access token from header

Answer (score 0):

One way is to send encrypted details from the server using RSA or 3DES Algorithm and decrypt the token on the client using the secret key by CryptoJS.

Another way is to use CryptoJS to encrypt/decrypt your token by a secret key. In this way, you cannot change the details the first time token enters the client.

follow the following guide to achieve it. 
https://www.davidebarranca.com/2012/10/crypto-js-tutorial-cryptography-for-dummies/

Comment: my access token is visible in header so.  The token isn't secret to the client (e.g. a user with a browser). They can do whatever they want with the token. They could copy/paste the token into Postman and play with the API there

Comment: That's why I said you need to encrypt it. Anyone cannot play around with an encrypted token. They need a decryption key for it. without decryption any secret is useless.